# Is there a way to count the length of a daisy chain of internal table references using Pandas / Python?

Tags: python, pandas, reference, networkx, graph-theory

We've a table that contains an Id, and on the same row, a reference to another Id in the same table. The Id record was infected by the referenced Id record. The referenced Id itself may or may not have a reference to another Id, it may not exist, or it may become a circular reference (linking back upon itself). Put into pandas, the problem looks a bit like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# example data frame
inp = [{'Id': 1, 'refId': np.nan},
   {'Id': 2, 'refId': 1},
   {'Id': 3, 'refId': 2},
   {'Id': 4, 'refId': 3}, 
   {'Id': 5, 'refId': np.nan},
   {'Id': 6, 'refId': 7},
   {'Id': 7, 'refId': 20},
   {'Id': 8, 'refId': 9},
   {'Id': 9, 'refId': 8}, 
   {'Id': 10, 'refId': 8}
   ]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
print(df.dtypes)
```

What I am trying to do is count of how far back the references go for each row in the table. The logic would:

- Starting with Result = 0 for each row:
- If a Ref-Id is not nan, then add 1,
- If the referenced-Id exists, and this referenced-Id has a reference, and the referenced-Id reference is not a back-reference, add 1 to the Result, then
  repeat this step until one of the conditions is NOT met, then go to
  Else;
- Else (no reference-Id, no reference for the referenced-Id, or
  reference loops back to a previous reference), return the Result.

Results from example should look like:

```
Id  RefId  Result
1     -      0
2     1      1
3     2      2
4     3      3
5     -      0
6     7      2
7     20     1
8     9      1
9     8      1
10    8      2
```

Every approach I've tried ends up needed a new column for each reference to a reference, but the table is quite enourmous, and I'm not sure how long the daisy-chain of internal table references will ultimately be. I'm hoping there might be a better way, that isn't too difficult for me to learn.

Comment: Why the result for Id 7 is 1 and not 0? The referenced Id 20 does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a graph problem, so you can use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html).

Convert your dataframe to directed graph:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.fillna(-1).astype(int),
                            source='Id', target='refId',   # source -> target
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph()      # directed graph
                            )

# removing the NaN (replaced by "-1" for enabling indexing)
G.remove_node(-1)
```

This give this graph:

[image: graph]

Then simply count the children:

```
nodes = {n: len(nx.descendants(G,n)) for n in G.nodes}

df['Result'] = df['Id'].map(lambda x: nodes.get(x, 0))
```

output:

```
   Id  refId  Result
0   1    NaN       0
1   2    1.0       1
2   3    2.0       2
3   4    3.0       3
4   5    NaN       0
5   6    7.0       2
6   7   20.0       1
7   8    9.0       1
8   9    8.0       1
9  10    8.0       2
```

*NB. the result is a bit different, so maybe I did not fully grasp your logic, but this gives you the general idea. Please elaborate on the logic.*

Comment: This is a remarkable package to trace and count internal table back-references. I'm still trying to work out how the DiGraph method works, but it's as if it were written exactly for the use-case of bouncing around inside a table of self-referencing objects. It even coped with four cases that referenced themselves (I didn't know about this data entry error), and counted them as zero - perfect because it's not really a reference is it! A HUGE thank you for showing me something I wasn't sure how to even ask for.